# Как передать данные в 2 места

Tags: php

Возник вопрос. Есть html-файл в котором идет заполнение некой формы входа в "Личный кабинет". Заполняются поля: "номер карты" и "пин", данные оттуда передаются видимо в некую базу данных. После этого идет переход в "Личный кабинет", в котором в свою очередь заполняются контактные данные. Примерно это выглядит так:

```
<form method="post" onSubmit="return check(this)" action="lk/account.html" 
class="lk" name="lk">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Номер карты</td>
<td><input id="numcard" onkeyup='checkParams()' class="data" name="numcard" 
type="text" placeholder="Ваш номер карты" title="12-значный номер карты" >
</td>
</tr>           
<tr>
<td>PIN</td>
<td><input id="pin" onkeyup='checkParams()' class="data" name="pss" 
type="text" placeholder="Введите Ваш пароль"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;"><input class="button data" 
type="submit" name="" value="Войти"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Мне нужно вывести данные, которые вводит клиент в отдельном файле (там висит виртуальный сертификат, где автоматически вводятся его контактные данные). Нашел где достать все данные кроме PIN (типа пароля получается). Как их можно достать?

Comment: `$_POST['pss']` не подходит?

Comment: так method="post" уходит в account.html разве нет? могу ли я $_POST ловить его в другом файле?

Comment: Нет. Вот в этом файле и сделайте всю обработку

Comment: Т.е. если есть method="post" action="lk/account.htm    я все равно смогу допустим в файле card.php применить $_POST['pss']???

Comment: Нет. Массив `$_POST` не передается между страницами. Он отправляется с клиента на сервер один раз при отправке формы и именно туда, куда попросили. И именно там, куда он отправлен и должна происходить вся обработка

Comment: Тогда в связи с этим другой вопрос: как мне теперь со страницы account.html взять эти обработанные данные, а именно $_POST['pss'] и сделать так чтобы они отображались или каким-то образом были перенесены в файл card.php. Просто в этом файле (card.php) выводится картинка на которой выведены данные клиента. Все остальные данные я смог вытащить из БД через         
 <?=$r['name']?> (вместо 'name' в других полях еще идут 'sname', 'tel' и другие данные). всё это засунуто в output и прекрасно все выводит. А вот вводимый PIN (пароль) не могу найти где зацепить.

Comment: Записать его куда-то. В сессию или ту же БД

Comment: Большая просьба: приведите примерчик. С PHP к сожалению знаком пару недель только и то шапочно.

Comment: Функция `include`  (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php) вам в помощь